# Python Singleton works just for one script

Tags: python, singleton

I have a database connection which is supposed to be built as a singleton. The singleton code is the following:

```py
class Singleton(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            cls._instances[cls] = super(Singleton, cls).__call__(
                *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instances[cls]
```

And I set up the class like this (of course methods are acutally not empty):

```py
class DatabaseHandler(metaclass=Singleton):
   
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def method1(self):
        pass
```

I created two files with the exact same code

```py
from databasehandler import DatabaseHandler

while True:
    db = DatabaseHandler()
    print(id(db))
    time.sleep(1)
```

and when I execute them both the id of the Databasehandler-objects remains the same within their script however it differs between the two scripts. What is the reason for that?

Comment: How do you execute these two scripts? Both with `python scriptname,py` or one script from the other script?

Comment: In two seperate terminals with python scriptname.py

Comment: You are creating 2 completely different python processes. They are independet from each other and don't share anything. They are two different programs, so to speak

Comment: Alright, thanks for the answer. Fixed it with running multiple threads.